# Angular + HTML 5 pushstate error

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have Angular version 1.2.16, and my module is configured like this:

```
publicApp.angularModule = angular.module('Public', [ 'ui.select2', 'infinite-scroll',  'ngSanitize',  'ui.utils'])
.config(function ($locationProvider) {
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

});
```

And In my controller I have this code:

```
  publicApp.angularModule.controller('PublicProfileMain', function ( $scope, $http) {

  $scope.onProgressClick = function () {
        removeClasses();
        progress.addClass("active");
        $scope.sourceMain = '/Templates/Pages/Public/Profile/ProfileStatsBasic.html';
        var stateObject = { url: "progress", type: "progress" };
        history.pushState(stateObject, "progress", "progress");
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'fast');

    };
});
```

Why Am I getting these errors ?

```
    "Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: [["fn: $locationWatch; newVal: 52; oldVal: 51"],["fn: $locationWatch; newVal: 53; oldVal: 52"],["fn: $locationWatch; newVal: 54; oldVal: 53"],["fn: $locationWatch; newVal: 55; oldVal: 54"],["fn: $locationWatch; newVal: 56; oldVal: 55"]]
```

**EDIT**

Is there way I can achieve deep linking with angular ?

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know why is this happening, and even more,  when I include this line:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

Angular messes up my server side routing (my whole routing is set up by ASP.net MVC, and I haven't configured any routes using Angular).

Best thing I've managed to come up whit is this:

Using $location I change URL like this:

```
$location.hash("feed");
```

Unfortunately because of this my urls now look smth. like this:

```
mysite.com/userName##feed
```

This could by avoided by setting html5Mode to true, but as I said it messes up with my ASP.net MVC routing ([here is SO link on my question about that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23413923/angular-locationprovider-with-asp-net-mvc-routing/23414055))

And I have stack where I push my urls, for example:

```
 $scope.onFeedClick = function () {
    removeClasses();
    feed.addClass("active");
    $scope.sourceMain = '/Templates/Pages/Public/Profile/ProfileFeed.html';
    //var stateObject = { url:"feed", type: "feed" };
    //history.pushState(stateObject, "feed",  "feed");

    $location.hash("feed");
    urls.push("feed");

    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'fast');
};
```

And my window.onpopstate looks like this:

```
 window.onpopstate = function() {

    urls.pop();
    var urlToSet = urls.pop();

    if (urlToSet == "progress") {

        $scope.onProgressClick();
        $scope.$apply();

    }
    else if (urlToSet == "feed") {

        $scope.onFeedClick();
        $scope.$apply();

    }
    else if (urlToSet == "profile") {
        $scope.onHomeClick();
        $scope.$apply();

    }

};
```

Also I'm handling refresh this way:

```
 var hash = $location.hash();

if (hash) {

    if (hash == "profile") {
        $scope.onHomeClick();



    }
    else if (hash == "feed") {

        $scope.onFeedClick();


    }
    else if (hash == "progress") {

        $scope.onProgressClick();

    }
}
```

I don't know is this best solution for my problem (or even correct one) but it works, I welcome any suggestions and improvements;